# Is there a difference between running projects in IntelliJ and geany?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, geany

I am very new to programming so sorry for the probably stupid question(s).

I have written my assignment for uni in IntelliJ (and when I run the whole project in IntelliJ it works just fine), but when I try to compile the class with the main method in it in geany (the IDE we used when we started out) it can't find any imports and says the package doesn't exist.

Is there a difference in how a program is executed when I run it in IntelliJ versus in Geany?

Is it because IntelliJ sees the whole source folder and in Geany I can only execute one single file?

Answer (score 0):

Either there's something wrong with your code or your Geany environment is not setup properly to run a Java program.

Is this the first time you've tried to run Java after a fresh install of Geany?

Try running a simple HelloWorld Java program in Geany and see what happens...

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

If you're environment is not setup correctly, Google "how to install Java Geany" and follow the instructions.

Comment: Hello @Surronie , welcome on Stackoverflow. I think this is not an acceptable  answer, rather a comment. Take a look on [how to make a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to help yourself.